# Is it possible to add breakpoints to a class which I don't have the source code for?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I want to add a breakpoint in a class in Eclipse, but I don't have the source code for it.  Is it possible to add a breakpoint in it anyway?  In my case I really only need to know when a method is called.

(As a side note: does anyone have the source code for j2ee_api_1_3.jar?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download jad decompiler /configure its path in eclipse through windows->preferences and open the source of the class where you need to place the breakpoint - and  then debug can run as it does normally and you can see all the variable information in the variable view.

Comment: Jadclipse (http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net) with Jad (http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) solved it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you open the outline view, you can select a method, right-click and select **Toggle Method Breakpoint**, this will then break whenever the method is hit.

You may be able to get the sources from Sun's [archive download page](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Rich, the [outline view](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-30.htm) (available even without sources):

[alt text http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/ref-8.png](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/ref-8.png)

allows you to set **[method breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-set_method_breakpoints.htm)**, that is, provided [javac compiled those classes with debug informations, including "Source Code information"](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) (that is the case [with J2EE1.4](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/devguide/dgdebug.html), not sure about J2EE1.3)

The source code of [J2EE 1.3 should be available](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/faq.html#source) and be included with the [download center](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=7917-j2ee_sdk-1.3.1-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer) j2sdkee-1_3_1-win.exe file.

Comment: Depressingly, my copy of j2ee1.3 hasn't got debug or source code information, and the source code isn't available in the download that you found.  (I admire your google-fu for finding it, though :))

Answer (score 1):

It depends, I think, on whether the class was compiled with debug information. If so, then the class file contains meta-data such as line numbers and parameter names which the debugger needs to make a decent fist of it. If not, then the debugger has less information to go on.

JavaEE libraries are notorious for not having debug meta-data compiled into them. It can be quite frustrating.