# Debugging class files

Tags: java, class, debugging, tomcat, web

In my project I have 2 war files deployed in Tomcat. One war file is my project which I can debug in Eclipse. Second war file is a framework war and I don't have the project source.

When I run my web application, all the calls will be gone through this framework to my project. So if there's any error in that path before reaching my project, I am not able to figure out. Is there any way to debug the class files.

Thanks,

SD

Answer (score 4):

You can use decompiler for the .class files that you don't have sources for. However, the result is never identical, and you will lose comments and some other things. The result is just a one possibility of what the source code could be based on the byte code. Still, it might help, I know it has helped me time to time.

Some examples of dava decompilers are [JAD](http://varaneckas.com/jad/), [JD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler), and [Fernflower](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2029842). At least for JAD there's an [eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/) as well.

Comment: I am using JAD but I am not sure how to put breakpoints and debug class files in Eclipse. Is there any link ?

Comment: @user184794 the same way you put them in your files normally. When you click on a class file, with decompiler integration you'll see an approximation of source code, and you should be able to put breakpoints.

Comment: see also [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299489/is-it-possible-to-add-breakpoints-to-a-class-which-i-dont-have-the-source-code), though it tells you the same thing